# Connection Failed Database-Zabbix

Tags: database, postgresql, error-handling, zabbix, failed-installation

I received this error after updating Zabbix from 5 to 6 for my database:

```
 # cat /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log | grep database
 55202:20220803:093334.621 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [0] FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
 55202:20220803:093334.621 database is down: reconnecting in 10 seconds
 55202:20220803:093344.636 database connection re-established
 55202:20220803:093344.639 current database version (mandatory/optional): 05000000/05000005
  1117:20220807:163451.680 current database version (mandatory/optional): 05000000/05000005
```

The following one is in my zabbix webpage:

```
The Zabbix database version does not match current requirements. Your database version: 5000000. Required version: 6000000. Please contact your system administrator.
```

I use postgresql!Zabbix and Postgresql services are active!

Comment: There is probably a database upgrade script you have to run to update the data structures to V6 too

Comment: Could you please explain more or give me a link?

Comment: I have never upgraded a zabbix installation myself, I am just reading the error message you posted. There will be an upgrade guide in the documentation

Comment: I made a mistake! There was a problem with the database version not being compatible with the new Zabbix version.